# Bcrypt compareSync function throws illegal arguments error

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I am trying to login a user by getting username and password inside post request.I make it so that every user has unique username.But when i try to check if user entered the right password by comparing password from the request with the hashed password returned from the database so i can send back a token if they match i get this Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined.

Here is the code:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {

    User.find({ username: req.body.username }, (err, data) => {

        var passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, data.password);
        if (err) return res.send(err);
        if (data.length === 0 || !passwordIsValid) return res.json({ msg: "Invalid credentials." });
        var token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, 'supersecret', {
            expiresIn: 86400 // 24 hours

        });

        res.json({ auth: true, token: token });

    });

});
```

Comment: Okay, and the error is still of illegal arguments in the line of bcrypt.compareSync? Could you add the search result to the database?

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet here I did not understand `var token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, 'supersecret', {`, where did the `user._id` come from? The change in this line should resolve, perform the test advise if you succeed.

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {

    User.find({ username: req.body.username }, (err, data) => {

        var passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, data.password);
        if (err) return res.send(err);
        if (!passwordIsValid) return res.json({ msg: "Invalid credentials." });
        var token = jwt.sign({ id: data._id }, 'supersecret', {
            expiresIn: 86400 // 24 hours

        });

        res.json({ auth: true, token: token });

    });

});
```

If you prefer testing using async / await.

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {

    const user = await User.find({ username: req.body.username })
    if(!user){
        return res.send({Error: 'User does not exist'})
    }
    if(!await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)){
        return res.send({msg: 'Invalid credentials.'})
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({id: user._id}, 'supersecret',{
        expiresIn: 86400
    })
    res.json({ auth: true, token: token });

});
```

Later on i found this mistake instead of user._id it goes data._id but it still was not working it turns out that data is an array of objects because every username is unique it will always have only one object that holds info about user with given username so in order to access users password i need to write data[0].password instead of data.password.